# How to loop around a circle in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, nested-loops

Im working on a problem that is called the crazy pet store. Basically there are 35 bowls of fish arranged in a circle in a room. each bowl had a diff type and amount of fish in them. they are arranged as follows:

```
Bowls 1 – 3: 15 fish
Bowls 4 – 7: 8 fish
Bowl 8: 19 fish
Bowls 9 – 12: 16 fish
Bowls 13 – 22: 14 fish
Bowls 23 – 24: 31 fish
Bowls 25 – 29: 9 fish
Bowls 30 – 33: 26 fish
Bowls 34 – 35: 8 fish
```

There's a seal who eats a total of 361 fish -- one from every 4th bowl starting with bowl #4, then #8, #12, #16 etc. Im trying to figure out how to calculate the number and type of fish left after the seal eats 361 fish. For some reason the tiger fish calculation is off and I cant figure out why.(the seal isnt eating any tiger fish)Below is my program

````
int main()
{
    //variable declaration
    int seal, bowl = 0, goldCount = 0, gupCount = 0, angelCount = 0, tigerCount = 0, totalFish = 0, fishEaten = 0, x = 0, num = 0, currentBowl = 3;

    //array with # of fish in bowls
    int fishNum[35] = { 15, 15, 15, 8, 8, 8, 8, 19, 16, 16, 16, 16,
                        14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 31,
                        31, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 26, 26, 26, 26, 8, 8 };  // initialize the number of fish in bowls

    //initialize type of fish in bowls
    string fishType[35] = { "goldfish", "goldfish", "goldfish", "goldfish", "goldfish", "goldfish",
                            "guppies", "guppies", "guppies", "guppies", "guppies", "guppies", "guppies",
                            "angel", "angel", "angel", "angel", "angel", "angel", "angel", "angel", "angel",
                            "goldfish", "goldfish", "goldfish", "goldfish", "goldfish", "goldfish", "goldfish", "goldfish",
                            "tiger", "tiger", "tiger", "tiger", "tiger" };

    //THIS ANSWERS QUESTION A1 which lists the # and type of fish in each bowl
    cout << "The number and type of fish in each bowl is as follows: " << endl;
    for (int bowl = 0; bowl <= 34; bowl++)
    {
        num++;
        cout << "Bowl " << num << " - " << fishNum[bowl] << " " << fishType[bowl] << endl;
    }
    //go through array and link fishNum to fishType
    for (int x = 0; x <= 35; x++)
    {
        if (fishType[x] == "goldfish")
            goldCount += fishNum[x];
        else if (fishType[x] == "guppies")
            gupCount += fishNum[x];
        else if (fishType[x] == "angel")
            angelCount += fishNum[x];
        else if (fishType[x] == "tiger")
            tigerCount += fishNum[x];
    }

    //calculates total number of fish
    totalFish = (goldCount + gupCount + angelCount + tigerCount);

    //THIS ANSWERS QUESTION B1
    cout << "\nTo begin, there are " << totalFish << " total fish. There are " << goldCount << " gold fish, " 
        << gupCount << " guppies, " << angelCount << " angel fish, and " << tigerCount << " tiger fish." << endl;
    

    //traverese through bowls in the room
    while (fishEaten < 361)
    {
        {//keeps track of type of fish eaten
        if (fishNum[bowl] > 0)
            if (fishType[bowl] == "goldfish")
                goldCount--;
            else if (fishType[bowl] == "guppies")
                gupCount--;
            else if (fishType[bowl] == "angel")
                angelCount--;
            else 
                tigerCount--;
        }
        if (fishNum[bowl] > 0)              //if bowl isnt empty...
        {
            fishNum[bowl]--;                //eat one fish
            fishEaten++;                    //add one to fish eaten tally
            bowl + 4;                       //go to next 4th bowl
        }
        else
        {
            bowl++;                         //if bowl is empty, go to next bowl
        }
        bowl %= 35;                         //wraps around the 35 bowls
    }

    //answer to B2
    cout << "The number of fish eaten is: " << fishEaten << endl;
    cout << "There are " << totalFish - fishEaten << " fish left over once the seal is done eating." << endl;
    
    //didnt eat any tiger fish
    cout << "\nThere are " << goldCount << " gold fish, " << gupCount << " guppies, " << angelCount << " angel fish, and " << tigerCount << " tiger fish." << endl;


    return 0;
}```

Can anyone point out why the tiger fish calculation isnt working?
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 1) Are you familiar with the modulo operation (`%` in C++)? 2) It's best to ask only one question at a time. 3) It helps to be precise about what you mean; *"skip an empty bowl"* could mean that if bowl #20 is empty the seal should proceed to bowl #21, or to bowl #24, and *"not working properly"* could mean quite a lot of different things. 4) When you write code, start simple and build up. For instance, try getting the seal to visit every bowl in the circle, without disturbing the fish, and don't try more until that is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the modulo operator, to wrap around. For example:

```
int bowl = 0;
while (fishEaten < 361)
{
    fishNum[bowl]--;
    fishEaten++;

    bowl = (bowl + 4) % 35; // this goes 4 bowl further, wrapping around
}
```

If you want to skip empty bowls, just add logic for it:

```
int bowl = 0;
while (fishEaten < 361)
{
    if (fishNum[bowl] > 0)
    {
        fishNum[bowl]--;
        fishEaten++;
    }

    // advance even if the bowl was empty
    bowl = (bowl + 4) % 35; // this goes 4 bowl further, wrapping around
}
```